# Selenium scrolling down dynamic site

Tags: python, selenium, scroll, youtube, comments

I am attempting to scroll down a youtube site using python selenium. My problem is that when i run the code below to extract the height of the page i always get a zero.

```
pageEnd = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
```

The following code manages to scroll down but i would like to replace the 10000 value with the pageEnd variable and iterate it using while loop.

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 10000)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for i in range(1,4):
      #scroll
      driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.bodt.scrollHeight)')
       
      #sleep a little bit
      time.sleep(3)
```

it will scroll and wait the contents to load and scroll again according to the range number

Comment: This one does not work because the body.scrollHeight always returns a value of zero thus making the page stay at the top.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code with a `while` loop -

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

yourElement.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

Comment: I'll try this one.. Thanks

Comment: What would i have to place on the "yourElement" part ?Because i replaced it with the "driver" but it returned an error saying that WebDriver does not have send_keys attribute

Comment: You have to use the webelement there.

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)` use this code.

Comment: I just tried it right now it does not scroll all the way to the bottom but it scrolls one page down